# Coded UI Automation

Tags: coded-ui-tests

If we have used standard console output in our automated test cases, it will be displayed in test results window under "Console Output"
How to display the same console output from our test results window in MTM when the playback has finished?
By default it gives a single result as "Test case Passed".What should we do to display the same console output to be as a result in MTM also?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're doing something along the lines of `Console.Writeline("It didn't work.");` and wanting to have that string output into MTM.  My suggestion would be to use something like the following:

```
public ReusableAssertion
{
    public AssertIsTrue(bool value, string message)
    {
        // This will have your 'message' string appear in MTM
        Assert.IsTrue(value, message);
        // If you want to still have your flat file or console logging, do it here:
        Log.WriteLog(message);
    }
}
```

Then, in your test, you would just use the reusable assertion in place of the basic `Assert.Fail()` or `Assert.Pass()`.  You would, of course, create methods for Assert.IsTrue, Assert.IsFalse, Assert.AreEqual, etc.

Hope that helps.